# Translation resources are not manually added to the executable file

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, localization, resources

I've created a small test project to demonstrate my issue.

The essence of the problem is that, according to the official documentation for `qt_add_translations`, the two code examples I've provided below should be roughly equivalent. Moreover, according to the functions `qt_add_lupdate`, `qt_add_lrelease`, and `qt_add_resources`, translation files should be added to the executable file.

However, for some reason, when using the `second variant`, translation files are not added to the executable file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

project(TestQtWidgetsProject)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

# Executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

# Library
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt::Core Qt::Gui Qt::Widgets)

# Translations
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED LinguistTools)

# =======================================

# Variant 1

#qt_add_translations(TestQtWidgetsProject
#        INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
#            ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
#        TS_FILES
#            translation_ru.ts)

# Variant 2

qt_add_lupdate(${PROJECT_NAME} INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} TS_FILES translation_ru.ts)
qt_add_lrelease(${PROJECT_NAME} TS_FILES translation_ru.ts QM_FILES_OUTPUT_VARIABLE QM_FILES)
qt_add_resources(${PROJECT_NAME} "translations" PREFIX "/i18n" FILES ${QM_FILES})

# =======================================

# Dependencies
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME}_lupdate)
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME}_lrelease)
```

`main.cpp`

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QTranslator>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTranslator translator;

    qDebug() << translator.load(":/i18n/translation_ru");
    qDebug() << QApplication::installTranslator(&translator);

    QPushButton button(QApplication::tr("Hello, World!") + QApplication::tr(" qwe"), nullptr);
    button.resize(200, 100);
    button.show();
    return QApplication::exec();
}
```

Output when using the first variant:

```
true
true
```

Output when using the second variant:

```
false
false
```

Comment: Looking at the "This is roughly equivalent to the following:" block in the documentation I'd guess that the missing `BASE` in `qt_add_resources` would be the issue https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtlinguist-cmake-qt-add-translations.html"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `qt_add_resources` function call, it is needed to add the `BASE` parameter equal to the path of the folder from which resource file aliases are resolved.

For example, if you set `BASE` as `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}`, then

```cpp
translator.load(":/i18n/translation_ru")
```

will return `true`,
whereas if you set `BASE` as `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}`, to load the translation file, you'll need to write:

```cpp
translator.load(":/i18n/cmake-build-debug/translation_ru");
```

(this example is provided for better understanding)

Thus the correct code for the second variant would be:

```
qt_add_lupdate(${PROJECT_NAME} INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} TS_FILES translation_ru.ts)
qt_add_lrelease(${PROJECT_NAME} TS_FILES translation_ru.ts QM_FILES_OUTPUT_VARIABLE QM_FILES)
qt_add_resources(${PROJECT_NAME} "translations" PREFIX "/i18n" BASE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} FILES ${QM_FILES})
```